# How to pass html options to another html file?

Tags: html

I am new in web development so please don't judge .
So let's say I have 2 html files ( x.html and y.html) (just 2 examples). 
And on x.html the user can change the background  from white to black using a button ( clicking the button will make the transition ) . What is want is that when the user has changed the value on x.html to appear the same on y.html ( black background aswell ).
So my question is?
What i need to do this and how can I make this?
Thanks for reading

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript and cookies/localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new in HTML this might seem really difficult (it did to me when I was new). To actually build such applications I highly recommend that you learn CSS followed by JavaScript.

Once you know that you'll automatically know how you can pass "HTML Options" (aka variables) between files.

The actual answer is through cookies. You set the background color as a cookie in the browser from one HTML page, the other HTML page will read the cookie and set the background accordingly.

Cookies are shared between HTML pages.

You might find this tutorial about [web storage API](http://www.stronia.com/p/building-app-using-web-storage-api.html) useful too if you want web storage instead of cookies.

The thing about web storage api is that the web storage API doesn't share information with your server. (It's explained in my tutorail that I've linked).

### Tutorials for reference:

- [W3Schools' page on JavaScript cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
- My article on [web storage API](http://www.stronia.com/2014/07/web-storage-in-html5.html) and [tutorial series](http://www.stronia.com/p/building-app-using-web-storage-api.html).

Comment: Thanks , I know html and css , some jqeury, and let's say basic javascript ( founded that jquery is more suitable for me ) . So I have to learn those cookies it seems :D

Comment: Yes @LKB You have to learn to use cookies (I've linked a w3schools page about cookies)

Comment: Moreover if you want to use the Web Storage API (considered more modern by few) I've linked that as well...

Comment: Thanks , I've seen something about HTML5 Local Storage . What's that ?

Comment: HTML5 local storage is a JavaScript API that allows you to store key-value pairs in the browser. For example: "Background color" -> "yellow"

Comment: Do you have experience with some programming language like Python or PHP? I'll be able to explain in that context then...

Comment: Sadly , i don't know , yet I am planning to learn PHP in the next months and also keep learning and practicing html ,css , java , jquery etc

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to set a cookie storing the change the user makes on your website.
When loading either x.html or y.html do a check with javascript to check if a cookie is set, and then display a background corresponding to the cookies value.

There are several ways of doing this, but I would suggest you to use google and learn how to create cookies with javascript and binding events to clicks on elements.

HTML is a static code which cannot hold parameters and send them along to other files.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer . I've found something about HTML 5 Local Storage . Is that good or should I go with javascript cookies?

Comment: Personally I have no experience with Local Storage yet. The disadvantage here as far as I know is that it is not supported by earlier browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The web is stateless, which means that every page request is separate and doesn't know about other requests. To maintain state between requests you need some kind of client storage which doesn't dissipate between requests, e.g a cookie, which is a small file saved on the client side as a key-value pair.

So, with regards to your question, you can use a plugin like [jquery cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) to create a cookie which will store the background color, and pull that cookie (if exists) on any other page in your domain. Then you can use simple jquery DOM manipulation functions, such as `.css` to apply the desired background color to the element in question

Answer (score 0):

you can use a plugin like jquery cookie to create a cookie which will store the background color, and pull that cookie (if exists) on any other page in your domain. Then you can use simple jquery DOM manipulation functions, such as .css to apply the desired background color to the element in question